# Getting user apple email

Tags: ios, objective-c

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor

An alphanumeric string that uniquely identifies a device to the app’s vendor.
I am using that, however I also want to get the user email address logged in into apple store. How can i get that via objective-c?

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]
```

Comment: I hope you can't.

Comment: or friendly ask your users for the address and see what happens when you loose trust to your costumers.

Comment: can i prompt user to list of his accounts defined in the phone?